# Minimum speed controller refresh rate

Tags: quadcopter, esc

In a quadrotor we need to change each motor's speed depends on its position in space. More frequency will result more stability ( I mean if we can change motor's speed 400 times per second instead of 100 times per second we may stabilize our UAV quadrotor far better ).

Now my question targeting people who made a UAV quadrotor before or have any information about ESCs. I wanna know whats the minimum refresh rate for ESCs in a quadrotor to make it stable ? For example may an ESC with 50hz refresh rate enough for stabilizing quadrotor or not ? I'm asking this question because high speed ESCs are more expensive than lower speed ones.

I have [this one](http://www.emaxmodel.com/views.asp?hw_id=21). May it work ?

Comment: Be careful about assuming that *faster is better* as it very much depends on the overall control system. If the response time of the physical system has a longer response time that of your control system and your tuning parameters are too aggressive, you may just be making matters worse. Also remember that you will have to retune the entire system whenever you change your control frequency.

Comment: Also, remember that [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) are better than hypothetical situations, so to get specific answers you might want to have a think how you can make the question more specific.

Comment: @MarkBooth ok you are right. I'll edit my question by considering your tips.

Comment: @MarkBooth in this case (I mean in control systems like PIDs for UAV) I think faster is better. Am I right ?

Comment: Comments are not a great place for discussions, but feel free to come over to [chat] and I'll be happy to discuss this.

Comment: @DavidCary yes, almost duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to do such an analysis, you should build up a Simulink/xcos model and derive such an analysis from that rather than make assumptions about such things which may or may not be directly correlated.